# How can I choose the right edition of extension for vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to install the `ssh` vscode extension offline by `Install from VSIX`. However, there is an error saying `Unable to install extension 'ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh' as it is not compatible with VS Code '1.39.2'`. Is there a table in which I can get the correct match between my vscode and extensions?

Comment: The reliable way is to keep VSCode fresh, just update it to latest version (November 2020  - version 1.52)

Comment: @DaniilLoban For many users who choose to install extension offline may not able to connect the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not appear to be a table listing all of the versions for the [Remote - SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) extension.  The package does not include a changelog file, and the [github page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release) is just a placeholder for filing issues (so there's no useful history information there either).

However, the [marketplace page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) has a "Version History" tab.  That tab only lists the past five versions (0.55.0 to 0.62.0 at time of writing), but hovering the mouse on a link shows the URL pattern, so if you know or can guess the names of past versions then you can download them.  For example, I guessed that 0.45.0 probably existed, and indeed it does: [link to version 0.45.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-vscode-remote/vsextensions/remote-ssh/0.45.0/vspackage).

Having downloaded the `vsix` file, you can unpack it by renaming the extension to `zip` and using any tool that understands the `zip` format (since that is what `vsix` is).  Then check the `package.json` inside it to see which version it requires.  In the case of 0.45.0, I see:

```
        ...
        "engines": {
                "vscode": "^1.36.0"
        },
        ...
```

meaning that version works with VSCode 1.36.0 and (in theory) greater.

You could keep doing that, using binary search, to find the best match for your version of VSCode.

If you need to do this for another extension(s), and that extension *does* have a changelog file, it should be linked on the Version History tab as well as contained in the latest `vsix` package, and reading that *may* be easier than binary searching among downloads, depending on how it is written.